# Why is my max_upload_filesize being limited to 2M?

Tags: php, uploads, limit

I have had to reinstall my wordpress install. In order to add the content back I need to get my max_upload_filesize increased to at least 500M. I have went to every php.ini I can find and increased the size. I have even done that in the .htaccess file. When I go to media panel to upload I still have a hard limit at 2M. Where do I need to make the change?

Comment: Maybe overridden somewhere using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Answer (score 1):

Do you by any chance didn't run `sudo service apache2 reload` or `sudo service apache2 restart` after making the changes on php.ini? To find out which php.ini you should update, run command `php --ini`.

Answer (score 0):

The php.ini file has to be in your root folder.

If modifying the php.ini and .htaccess doesnt work, you can try to add the following code to your functions.php file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Not sure if the last one is good practice, but some people achieve it this way.

If all the 3 cases doesnt work, then you are most likely on a shared hosting package.

In this case my advice is to contact your web hosting support. In most cases, the support could do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the "Upload Max Size" plugin to easily do this (although you do have to enter a byte- value rather than something like "5MB"). Works well for me, and easy enough (although you can do it by settings in config files).

Plugin here https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/